# how to change the attributes of a file in a network shared folder with perl?

Tags: perl, networking, attributes, visibility, shared

How to change the attributes of a file in a network shared folder to hidden.
How is this possible with perl?

Answer (score 1):

```
use Win32::File qw( GetAttributes SetAttributes );

my $qfn = "\\\\server\\share\\dir\\file";
# or: "//server/share/dir/file"

GetAttributes($qfn, my $attrs) or die $^E;
$attrs |= Win32::File::HIDDEN;
SetAttributes($qfn, $attrs) or die $^E;
```

[Win32::File](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Win32%3a%3aFile)

Notes:

- It's not documented, but `$^E` should provide the error message on error.
- Get-modify-set avoids clobbering any existing attributes.